# AddEventListener when a link is clicked that adds a class to an element on another page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, addeventlistener

Very new to JavaScript so wondering if this is even possible. I was told by a friend that React could do what I am looking for through routes. But I don't know React yet, and don't plan on learning it for a while.

I am currently working on a website. On the Index page there is a "services provided" section with a little info about the four services provided. For each service there is a read more  tag. On the services page I have cards that are set to show text with basic JavaScript when a button is clicked in their individual service cards.

I am wondering if it is possible to set up an event listener on click when the  tag on the index page is clicked so that a "show-text" class is added to the necessary service card. So when a user clicks on "read more" it takes them to the services page with the service they wanted to read more about, already open.

index.html

```
    <h2> Our services include:</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li class="service-provided">
                        <h3>HR office hours:</h3>
                            <p>
                            <a class="hr-office-hours read-more" href="services2.html">Read more... 
                            </a> 
                            </p>
                    </li>                        
                    <li class="service-provided">
                        <h3>Coaching for transformation:</h3>
                            <p>
                            <a class="coaching read-more" href="services2.html">Read more...
                            </a> 
                            </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="service-provided">
                        <h3>Training and supporting supervisors:</h3>
                            <p>
                            <a class=" supervisors read-more" href="services2.html">Read more...
                            </a> 
                            </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="service-provided">
                         <h3>Building human resources systems and practices that reflect your organization’s values:</h3>
                            <p>  
                            <a class="org-values read-more" href="services2.html">Read more...</a> 
                            </p>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
```

Services HTML-

```
    <div class="service-card hr-office-hours card" id="HROH">
                <div class="service-title">
                    <h2>HR office hours</h2>
                    <button type = "button" class = "service-btn">
                        <span class = "plus-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class = "minus-icon">
                             <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="service-text">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="class="service-card coaching card" id="CFT">
                <div class="service-title">
                    <h2>Coaching for transformation</h2>
                    <button type = "button" class = "service-btn">
                        <span class = "plus-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class = "minus-icon">
                             <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="service-text">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="service-card supervisors card" id="TS">
                <div class="service-title">
                    <h2>Training and supporting supervisors</h2>
                    <button type = "button" class = "service-btn">
                        <span class = "plus-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class = "minus-icon">
                             <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="service-text">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="class="service-card org-values card" id="BHRS">
                <div class="service-title">
                    <h2>Building human resources systems and practices that reflect your organization’s values</h2>
                    <button type = "button" class = "service-btn">
                        <span class = "plus-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class = "minus-icon">
                             <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="service-text">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
    const service = document.querySelectorAll('.service-provided');
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.service-card');

    service.forEach(function(readmore){
        const link = readmore.querySelector('.read-more');
           link.addEventListener('click', function(){
 
            cards.forEach(function(card){
        
                if (link.classList.contains('hr-office-hours') && cards.classList.contains('hr-office-hours')){
                    card.classList.add('show-text')
                } else if (link.classList.contains('coaching') && cards.classList.contains('coaching')){
                    card.classList.add('show-text')
                } else if (link.classList.contains('supervisors') && cards.classList.contains('supervisors')){
                    card.classList.add('show-text')
                } else if (link.classList.contains('org-values') && cards.classList.contains('org-values')){
                    card.classList.add('show-text')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, yes, perhaps add some parameters to the route?

Comment: hmmm. Excuse my ignorance. What is my route in this case? And what parameters might I add? Thanks!